Visual novel Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected end of JSON input
A while ago I downloaded Café Rouge, but due to time issues I had not played this title, yesterday I unzipped it and ran it without problems, the game started without any problem, the bad thing started the next day when trying to play now out of nowhere the screen would not load staying black, I spent the whole morning trying to fix it and apparently there is an error in the json syntax I don't understand why if all I did was open the game see the first dialogs to check that everything was fine, uninstalled and installed the game several times deleting the files even but nothing that error does not go away, I would appreciate help.
type here



index.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

    at initVNData (vndata.js:264)

    at init (stage.js:3)

    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (start.js:18)

    at fire (jquery.js:1037)

    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:1148)

    at Function.ready (jquery.js:433)

    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.js:103)

index.html:1 Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getChildByName' of undefined

    at Object.global.parseScreen (chrome-extension://bmggelhbgnngphanaoafonacodkiiojh/player.js:9712:29)

    at NWWindow.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://bmggelhbgnngphanaoafonacodkiiojh/player.js:74:38)

    at NWWindow.<anonymous> (extensions::nw.Window:161:16)

index.html:1 Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getChildByName' of undefined

    at Object.global.parseScreen (chrome-extension://bmggelhbgnngphanaoafonacodkiiojh/player.js:9712:29)

    at NWWindow.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://bmggelhbgnngphanaoafonacodkiiojh/player.js:74:38)

    at NWWindow.<anonymous> (extensions::nw.Window:161:16)

player.js:9712 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getChildByName' of undefined

    at Object.global.parseScreen (player.js:9712)

    at HTMLCanvasElement.<anonymous> (player.js:100)

    at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (jquery.js:3074)

    at HTMLBodyElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:2750)

I have only tried to install and uninstall it since as I mentioned this game ran successfully last night, it did not give any errors and the screen did not go black, I did not move anything to avoid making a bigger mistake
